# Image from file, Server MapPath

Tags: asp.net

Why does this work:

```
System.Drawing.Image imageBmp =
System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Image.jpg"));
imageBmp.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images2/Image.jpg"),  
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imageBmp);
```

And this not? (the filename is correct)

```
var fileName = Request.QueryString["name"];
System.Drawing.Image imageBmp = 
System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fileName));
imageBmp.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fileName),
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imageBmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

This line will try to save a file onto itself `imageBmp.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + fileName),
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);`

It should be `imageBmp.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images2/" + fileName),
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);`

Comment: That's what I have right now, I save it in a different folder (just forgot the 2 above..) Any other idea why it's not working?

Comment: What Image file name comes from QueryString? Is the image identified by Querystring really present in the '/images/' folder?

Comment: Yes, the file is present. Think it's really weird that first one is working and the other is not..

Comment: @s.e: Can you edit your question with correct info. since you mentioned (just forgot the 2 above.)